# Query nao identificando valor

Tags: mysql, sql

Comando SQL:

```
SELECT message, count(message) as amount
FROM `messages`
WHERE LENGTH(message) >= 4 AND amount < 30 AND message != '#ddd' AND message != 'ddd' 
GROUP BY message
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**#1054 - Unknown column 'amount' in 'where clause'**

por que ele nao identifica o amount sendo que ele foi definito logo no inicio?

Comment: @rray Oi? esse código nao e meu e sou um cado leigo..

Comment: @user3163662 Desconsidere o que eu escrevi, ele conta sim, a resposta (atualizada) do rray de fato está correta ([exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74baa/7)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível usar um [alias na clásula `WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html) nesse caso é necessario refazer a expressão novamente ou chamar a coluna pelo 'original', `WHERE` faz sua verificação linha a linha então não é possível agregar um valor nela o que deve ser feito é agrupar o resultado com `GROUP BY` e depois fazer a verificação com a cláusula `HAVING` que faz mesma coisa que o `WHERE` porém ela trabalha com resultados agregados.

```
SELECT message, count(message) as amount
FROM `messages`
WHERE LENGTH(message) >= 4 AND message != '#ddd' AND message != 'ddd' 
GROUP BY message
HAVING count(message) < 30
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Comment: @mgibsonbr quando fiz a primeira resposta imaginei que so o `count` resolveria depois do outro erro lembrei do `having`.